# How can I redirect my URL to rearrange the order of subdirectories in .htaccess?

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, subdirectory, regular-expression

My current URL is

```
example.com/example/{dynamic_id}/{dynamic_name}/static/1.html
```

I want to redirect it to this,

```
example.com/{dynamic_name}/example/{dynamic_id}/static/1.html
```

I tried but failed.

Comment: Internal "rewrite" or external "redirect"? "My current url is" - Are you wanting to _change_ your current URL structure? "i tried but failed." - what did you try? What format can the `{dynamic_id}` and `{dynamic_name}` take?

Comment: i want to redirect my old urls to new urls instead of 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(example)/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/(static/1\.html)$ /$3/$1/$2/$4 [R=302,L]
```

This externally "redirects" a URL of the form `/example/{dynamic_id}/{dynamic_name}/static/1.html` to `/{dynamic_name}/example/{dynamic_id}/static/1.html`.

I'm assuming that `{dynamic_id}` consists of only digits and `{dynamic_name}` is alphanumeric and can include underscores (`_`) and hyphens (`-`).

`$1`, `$2`, `$3` and `$4` are backreferences to the corresponding captured groups in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*.

**UPDATE:** Specifically, the regular expression (regex) `^(example)/(\d+)/([\w-]+)/(static/1\.html)$` matches as follows:

- `^` - asserts the start of the string. So whatever follows matches from the beginning of the URL-path.
- `(example)` - matches the literal string "example" (at the start of the URL-path - note that the URL-path that is matched does not start with a slash). The surrounding parentheses `(` ... `)` make this a *capturing group*, which can later be referenced in the *substitution* string using `$1` (the number indicates the position of the capturing group in the regex). Capturing this simply saves repetition later, as we can refer to this using `$1`, instead of having to repeat the word "example". This is a simple example but is good practice to save repetition of longer strings.
- `/` - matches a literal slash.
- `(\d+)` - matches 1 or more digits (ie. 0-9). `\d` is a shorthand character class that matches a digit 0-9. And the `+` quantifier matches 1 or more of these. Again, this is a capturing group, so is saved in the backreference `$2`.
- `([\w-]+)` - matches 1 or more *word* (or hyphen) characters. The `\w` is a shorthand character class indicating a *word* character, ie. `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` or `_`. The hyphen (`-`) is added to the character class. This is another capturing group, so is saved in the backreference `$3`.
- `(static/1\.html)` - matches the literal string "static/1.html". The dot (`.`) is a special meta-character that matches *any* character, so we need to backslash-escape the dot to match a literal dot. This is saved in the backreference `$4`.
- `$` - asserts the end of the string. So, the regex that occurs between the `^` (start) and `$` (end) must match the entire URL-path.

> can u solve this too, `example.com/static/{dynamic_id}/{dynamic_name}.html` to `example.com/{dynamic_name}/static/{dynamic_id}.html`

> i tried this but did't work.
> `RewriteRule ^(example)/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ /$3/$1/$2.html [R=302,L]`

That is very close, but you are just missing the `.html` (specifically `\.html` in regex syntax) from the end of the last path segment, since you need to match `{dynamic_name}.html`, not just `{dynamic_name}`. (Without capturing the ".html" part.)

Consequently the above will fail to match and it just won't do anything (or it matches the wrong URL and redirects incorrectly).

So, you would need to change it slightly like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(static)/(\d+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ /$3/$1/$2.html [R=302,L]
```

The order of the two rules does not matter in this instance as there does not appear to be a conflict.

However, one thing to be aware of is redirect-loops. Where the URL you are redirecting "to" also matches a URL-pattern you are redirecting "from". But that looks OK here.

> i want to redirect my old urls to new urls instead of 404

Note that the above are currently 302 (temporary) redirects. However, if you are redirectign "old" URLs then you probably want to change these to 301 (permanent) at some point. Always good to test with 302s to avoid potential caching issues.

Comment: can u solve this too, 
`example.com/static/{dynamic_id}/{dynamic_name}.html` to `example.com/{dynamic_name}/static/{dynamic_id}.html` which is very similar but with just 3 path segments instead of 4.
@MrWhite

Comment: That is left as an exercise for the reader ;) - it's exactly the same principle as above. Have a go, if you get stuck, post your attempt and I'll have a look.

Comment: i tried this but didn't work.
`RewriteRule ^(example)/(\d+)/([\w-]+)$ /$3/$1/$2.html [R=302,L]`

Comment: Looks like you are just missing the `.html` part from the end of the last path segment, so the above will fail to match. I've updated my answer with more explanation about the regex and addressed this secondary URL redirect.